# Paste a value in Excel exactly as is visible

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple request, to paste the data exactly as *visible* in Excel.

I have a list of dates in `mm/yyyy` format, but Excel keeps adding `mm/dd/yyyy` which is throwing off my analysis.  It's formatted to show simply `mm/yyyy` but the actual cell value keeps getting set to `mm/01/yyyy`.

How can I simply copy/paste the value to be `mm/yyyy`.

[image]

I've tried `Range("A1").Value = Range("A1").Value`, but of course that just keeps the same info.

<sub>Yes, in my case since it's dates, I can do a kludgy function that takes the left three characters, and combines with the rightmost four.  However, that really just gets the date number returned. I tried on `G4` and get `4171730`.  Plus, I'd like to know how to do this with other types of cell values too (strings, numbers, etc.).</sub>

Comment: Did you try `Range("A1").Value = Range("A1").Text`?

Comment: @ScottCraner - I did, it keeps the same.  Which is odd, because I could have sworn that's what the answer would be.  Even tried a middle-man string variable:  `Set rng = Range("G4") // str = rng.text // rng.Value = str`  This keeps the actual value as `04/01/2014` oddly enough.  **But** `str` is correctly set to `04/2014`.  So that's definitely the right path.

Comment: There's also the `PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats` method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

save the value and the format then set the cell as text and assign the formatted value:

```
Sub test()
    Dim t As Variant
    t = Range("A1").Value2

    Dim x As String
    x = Range("A1").NumberFormat

    Range("A1").NumberFormat = "@"
    Range("A1").Value = Format(t, x)

End Sub
```

---

This also works

```
Sub test()
    Dim t As String
    t = Range("A1").Text

    Range("A1").NumberFormat = "@"
    Range("A1").Value = t

End Sub
```

Comment: beat me to it. I just finished forcing the text format in vba and i see this :(

Comment: Haha, beat me to it also, nice thinking and thanks so much!  I think the issue was indeed setting number format before the `Value`. Cheers Scott!

Answer (score 3):

```
 Range("A1").Value = Format(yourdate, "mm/yyyy")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't work.  Using `Range("A1")` as my visible `04/2014`, that still keeps the actual value as `04/01/2014` :/

Comment: BRB going to play with this until i figure it out

Comment: Haha, yeah me too :D